# How to use GCP service account json files in Docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I am dockerizing Fastapi application which is using Firebase. I need to access `service json` file and I have configured my docker container as follows.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /requirements.txt
   
RUN mkdir /env
# Setup directory structure
COPY ./app /app/app
COPY ./service_account.json /env
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

**Docker-compose file**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    environment:
      - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_CLOUDAPI=${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_CLOUDAPI}
      - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}
    volumes:
      - ./env:/env

volumes:
  env:
```

Now when I run `docker-compose up -d --build` the container fails with the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/env/service_account.json'`. When I inspect the container I can see the `ENV` variable set successfully as shown `"GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/env/service_account.json",`. Now why is this failing?

Comment: Well, can you `ls /env` in the container and see that file listed in the error? Note: I dont think you want `env:` as a Compose-managed volume

Comment: When I ```ls``` I can see the files listed  as shown ```Step 12/13 : RUN echo $(ls /env)
 ---> Running in 0fd8edb0e70e
service_account.json```

Comment: You should use `docker-compose exec` rather than do that as a RUN command because you are mounting a volume at runtime, meaning your build-time files are hidden

Comment: Curiously, when I disable ```volumes``` in docker-compose file the error is gone and the container runs successfully. Why is that?

Comment: As answered below, the volume overrides the runtime directory. And your file is not in the env folder that you mounted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `context: .` and `COPY ./service_account.json /env`

But when you run the container, you have

```
volumes:
   - ./env:/env
```

Meaning your service_acccount file is not in `./env` folder, and is instead outside of it.

When you mount a volume, it replaces the directory inside the container, so if you need a local `env` folder mounted as `/env` in the container, then you should move your JSON file somewhere else such as `/opt` (`COPY ./service_account.json /opt`), and then set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/opt/service_account.json`

If you don't need the whole folder, then you only need

```
volumes:
   - ./service_account.json:/env/service_account.json:ro
```

Otherwise, move the JSON file into `./env` on your host and change `COPY ./env/service_account.json /env`